# Need help removing or hiding divs depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I was having trouble with changing a 3x3 image gallery layout on any screen **> than 768px** (tablet/desktop) to an image slider for any screen **< than 768px** (mobile).

After the help of everyone and especially **Danilo** (solutions in the comments), the problem was that the css was not correctly targetting the screen, I needed - *@media only screen*, I had also missed a **DIV**... (I know noob error).

So if anyone is trying to change the content displayed **from desktop layout to mobile layout** in **Bootstrap 4**, you can use **CSS media queries** that target the **wrapped DIV** to display or not display.

Updated working snippet below:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .slider {
        display: none;
    }
    .block {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .slider {
        display: block;
    }
    .block {
        display: none;
    }
}

.hold-tests {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.col {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
 <!--- Start of Gallery Section --> 
 <div id="hold-tests">
  <div class="col slider">
   <div id="sliderIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade z-depth-1-half" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <div class="carousel-inner col-" role="listbox">
     <!--- First Slide -->
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="Img/PHportrait.png" alt="background image">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="Img/PHportrait2.png" alt="background image">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="Img/PHportrait.png" alt="background image">
     </div>
    </div>
     <div class="narrow">
      <div class="col-12">
       <p class="lead text-center">Want to see more of my work?</p>
       <!-- add in social media icons and add target="_blank" to open in new tab -->
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="col block">
   <div id="gallery" class="offset">
    <div class="col-md">
     <div class="row no-padding">
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="gallery-card">
         <a href="Img/PHportrait.png" target="_blank">
          <img src="Img/PHportrait.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Gallery Picture">
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="gallery-card">
         <a href="Img/PHportrait.png" target="_blank">
          <img src="Img/PHportrait.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Gallery Picture">
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="gallery-card">
         <a href="Img/PHportrait.png" target="_blank">
          <img src="Img/PHportrait.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Gallery Picture">
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="gallery-card">
        <a href="Img/PHportrait.png" target="_blank">
         <img src="Img/PHportrait.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Gallery Picture">
        </a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="gallery-card">
        <a href="Img/PHportrait.png" target="_blank">
         <img src="Img/PHportrait.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Gallery Picture">
        </a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="gallery-card">
        <a href="Img/PHportrait.png" target="_blank">
         <img src="Img/PHportrait.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Gallery Picture">
        </a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="narrow">
     <div class="col-12">
      <p class="lead text-center">Want to see more of my work?</p>
       <!-- add in social media icons and add target="_blank" to open in new tab -->
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--- End of Gallery Section -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, just using CSS

html

```
<div class="hold-tests">
    <div class="col test1">Test1</div>
    <div class="col test2">Test2</div>
    <div class="col test3">Test3</div>
</div>
```

css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .test1 {
        display: none;
    }
    .test3 {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .test3 {
        display: none;
    }
}

.hold-tests {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.col {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: I've just tried what you've mentioned and edited the question to show. It works for mobile where the slideshow is only displayed, thanks! but on desktop it's still displaying both.

Comment: I've tried to duplicate the css media query and change the target to test1 but this removes both...

Comment: I've edited my solution. Do you want something like that?
You can play with the visibity as you want with @media query

Comment: Yeah thats worked for the mobile, the slideshow is displayed and the 3x3 is removed, but now neither are displaying on the desktop haha. For something so simple in my head this is proving much more difficult. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Your CSS ir good, but the problem is the HTML, I've fixed your snippet

Comment: The problem was that your test1 div was holdig all off your code, so I've just move it to hold just the first block of images and the test2 the second block

Comment: Yeah thats solved it, thank you! I knew there had to be something else, my own fault for not making sure the div's were closed correctly, but thanks for taking your time to look through and help me out :). I'll update the changed snippet in the question for others.

Comment: No problem...happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using bootstrap, use it. No jQuery needed for this, as it's completely covered already.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
  Only visible starting from md
</div>
<div class="d-md-none">
  Only visible on small screen
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

---

Also note that ids usually don't start with a `#`. Even though this may be legal, you'd then at least had to select them with $('##option1') in your jquery code.

Comment: Thanks chris but I've just tried it and at mobile width its still displays both the 3x3 and the slideshow. However, for desktop it doesnt display either now. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: That depends where you added the classes. Can you edit your question with what you tried so we can check please @Calum1300

Comment: Yeah I was trying to target them in jquery but forgot to remove the # before posting. Danilo's answer works for the mobile width but I'm still getting both displayed in desktop, do you know a work around?